# udapte datatable after RowFilter with filter results

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, rowfilter

applying filter on a `datatable` filled with all rows from table by using `RowFilter`

```
dtPatientInfo.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("FirstLastName LIKE '%{0}%'", TB_FirstLastName.Text);
```

after applying these filter I want to update this datatable with filter result only not original data

how I can bind the filter result to same datatable so it will lose any rows wont match the filter ?

**UPDATE**

as per answers and comment below I have made this but now the result data are moved to new `datatable` how move them to the old `datatable`?

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TB_FirstLastName.Text))
{
    DataView dv = new DataView(dtPatientInfo);
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("FirstLastName LIKE '%{0}%'", TB_FirstLastName.Text);
    DataTable newTable = dv.ToTable();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = newTable;
}
```

Comment: You might consider the [`ToTable()` method of the view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/creating-a-datatable-from-a-dataview)

Comment: @Crowcoder please see my post update

Comment: Reading this again I'm not sure what you mean by "update this datatable". Do you mean update a database?

Comment: @Crowcoder I mean that I have `datatable` lest say it called `dt1` which has a collection of rows bounded from database ... now user applied `rowfilter` on this `dt1` ... the data still has all bounded data not only the filtered ones... I need to keep search result and remove the unrelated row result so the `dt1` has only filter result ... the method you suggest did exactly what I want except it moves the result to a new `datatable` which is in that case called `newTable `

Comment: If you want to update a database with only the filtered rows then do not set the DataSource to the new table, just use the new table to make the updates, typically with a DataAdapter's `Update()` method. But then you should call `AcceptChanges()` on your DataSource so you don't grab the changes again.

Comment: @Crowcoder I do not want to touch the database ...

Comment: Then I do not understand your goal. I believe you think you have a problem that you don't really have.

Comment: @Crowcoder umm i have navigation button for the next previous record so when data filtered ... the navigation buttons navigate within the `dt1` ignoring the filters so I would apply the above scenario and navigation would be right when `dt1` has only the filtered data .... is it understandable ?

Comment: you might be navigating wrong, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-navigate-data-with-the-windows-forms-bindingnavigator-control

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that creates new table from filtered data:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.totable?view=netframework-4.7.2

DataView view = new DataView(table);
view.RowFilter = "QuantityInStock > 15";

DataTable newTable = view.ToTable("FilteredTable");

Comment: the result data are moved to a new datatable what I want is keeping the search result in same datatable

Comment: Well your old datatable is dtPatientInfo, so would it be as easy as:
dtPatientInfo = newTable.Clone(); //(from above code sample)
or if this doesn't work, clear old dt and forloop over newTable and insert rows one by one.